# Copy SSH Public Key to clipboard WITHOUT newline appended

Tags: command-line, ssh

Every Google search for copying a Mac's SSH Public Key to clipboard yields the following command, ***which results in a newline appended:***

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

This is undesirable as I need to paste a Public Key into a variable in an application I'm developing.  In the hopes of saving folks the trouble of solving the same problem, I'll post my solution to this question in the answers section-

Comment: Why not have the application remove the newline before using the public key?

Comment: I'll validate inputs and condition the data later- but for now a command that a user can copy-n-paste to provide the required input is sufficient.  Don't have the cycles now to think of every possible way folks can hose their inputs and code logic condition their data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To copy your SSH Public Key cleanly to clipboard WITHOUT a trailing newline use

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy
```

or (without `cat`)

```
tr -d '\n' < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy
```

Comment: Save yourself a command and a subshell `tr -d '\n' < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy`